# What are the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]\otimes \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$ is a localization of $\mathbb{Z}[t]$,  the multiplicative set consisting of the non-negative powers of $t$.

> But I do not know the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]\otimes \mathbb{Q}$. 
>    What is the invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]\otimes \mathbb{Q}$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Localizations need not be local. For example, $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ localized at the set $\{1, t, t^2, t^3, \dots\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$, which has many maximal ideals such as $(t-1)$, $(t-2)$, etc. Your ring is not local.

Comment: Prime (maximal) ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[t]_t=\mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]\cong \mathbb{Q}[t,x]/(tx-1)$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[t].$

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani: Not quite. The ideal $(t)$ is obviously not prime in $\mathbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, yeah, I should complete the statement by add those prime ideals of $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ with empty intersection with the multiplicative closed set $\{1,t,t^2,\cdots\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]\otimes \mathbb Q\cong \mathbb Q[t,t^{-1}]$ as this is just a special case of extension by scalars. Since $\mathbb Q[t,t^{-1}]\cong \mathbb Q[t]_{\{1,t,t^2,\ldots\}}$, its maximal ideals are in bijection with the maximal ideals of $\mathbb Q[t]$ which are disjoint from $\{1,t,t^2,\ldots\}$. Since $\mathbb Q[t]$ is a PID, the maximal ideals are $(p(t))$ for $p(t)$ a monic irreducible polynomial. This is disjoint from $\{1,t,t^2,\ldots\}$ unless $p(t)=t$, so the maximal ideals of $\mathbb Q[t,t^{-1}]$ are of the form $(p(t))$ with $p(t)\ne t$ an irreducible polynomial (WLOG with integer coefficients).

Under the isomorphism with $\mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$, these become $(p(t)\otimes 1)$ where $p(t)\ne t$ is irreducible, with positive leading coefficient and its coefficients have no common factor. 
By Gauss's lemma we do not need to distinguish between being irreducible over $\mathbb Z$ or over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Nitpick: But we do need to distinguish between $p(t)\neq t$ and $p(t)$ not associated to $t$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn That's a fair point, I'll add that detail.